# AngularJS loads at the very end

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am making an application using ASP.NET 4.5 Web forms and AngularJS 1.2.

I frequently encounter a problem in my web pages, angularjs takes time to load and during that time, the curly brace template expressions are not rendered correctly in the page.

I mean, I get these in my page while angularjs is still loading :

{{exp1}} will visit you on {{date}}

I those pages where my Page_Load asp.net function does a lot of work, this problem is more prominent. These template expressions stay on page for 3/4 seconds.

I tried to solve this using a loading gif, but I toggle the visibility of my loading gif using angular.js so its no good either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  in your body

```
<body ng-cloak>

</body>
```

and in your css

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a name to the issue that you see `flash-of-unstyled-content` or `fouc`

what you need to do is use `ng-cloak`, [link to its docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3AngCloak)

add `ng-clock` to body tag and `ng-cloak` css as shown it the earlier answer from @yang